# An open connected subset of compact metric connected and locally connected space, is path connected

Tags: general-topology

I need to prove:
If $X$ is compact, metric, connected and locally connected space, and $U$ is open connected subset of $X$, then $U$ is path connected.

Using the following:

*a)* If $X$ connected, and $F$ is open cover of $X$, then for every $a,b∈X$ exists an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and open sets $U_1 ,...,U_n∈F$ such that $a∈U_1$ and $b∈U_n$ and $U_i \cap U_j \neq \emptyset \leftrightarrow |j-i|=1$.

*b)* Every compact metric connected space with more than one point, has at least two non-cut points.

*c)* If $X$ is a compact metric connected space with exactly two non-cut points, then $X $ is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$.

*d)* If $X$ is a compact metric connected and locally connected space and $a,b∈X$, then there is a closed connected subset of $X$, where its points, apart from $a$ and $b$, are cut points.

I proved *a,b,c*, but I have trouble to build the subset in *d*.
and I can't figure how the theorem follows from *a,b,c,d*.

can anyone help me?

Comment: Could you spell out what you mean by d)? As it stands, you could just take the empty set as all elements of the empty set are cut-points.

Comment: @fuglede
But the empty set is not connected I think.

Comment: @MarikS.: That's a matter of convention. Also, if $X$ itself has no cut-points, the claim is problematic. The importance of $a$ and $b$ is unclear to me as well.

Comment: a,b,c,d should help me prove the theorem. therefore I think the empty set (if it is connected or not) won't help. The points a,b may be non-cut points (if we want to use c to prove the theorem).

Comment: What is this question?  You proved the Cut Point Non-Existence Theorem as *part* of a question?  And as the next part, the Moore classification of the arc?  Yeah right.  If you have the fact that a Peano continuum is path-connected then (d) is totally trivial, and if you don't have that fact then you need to prove the Hahn-Mazurkiewicz Theorem among many other facts, which takes pages and pages to do.  This is like some sort of 'fake news' of MSE posts haha